# When is preferredContentSize respected?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a table view controller which get it's content set after `viewDidLoad`. When setting the new content I calculate the `preferredContentSize`. Before I present the popover I can query the `preferredContentSize` of my view controller, which is correct. But after the presentation I get the standard size of the popover (320x480). If I use `setPopoverContentSize:animated:` with the before queried values everything works.

My question now is why doesn't it respect the `preferredContentSize` right in the beginning? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now I had the same problem another time. If I put my table height calculation into `viewWillAppear` than it works:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

    TableView.LayoutIfNeeded ();
    this.PreferredContentSize = new SizeF (320f, TableView.ContentSize.Height);
}
```

The code is in C# but you can easily convert it to Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: this solution work perfect with me. Thank you :D:D:D:D

Comment: It is not quite correct to do this in ViewWillAppear() simply because the table is not yet drawn and does not know its size (and sizes of cells). So TableView.LayoutIfNeeded is kind of useless unless your table has constant cell heights and is set up correspondingly.

Comment: @CynichniyBandera: And what do you propose instead? Where should it be called?

Comment: @testing A general recommendation to do it is in viewDidLayoutSubviews() code path when the view and its subviews have already got their real sizes (including localized strings, truncated labels with ellipsis, etc.) PS. You don't need re-layout your table. In viewDidLayoutSubviews() it is already updated.

Comment: @CynichniyBandera: Thanks for your response. Sounds reasonable. I'll try it the next time I have this problem. Feel free to add an answer if you want :)

Comment: @testing Welcome and let's keep it in the comments. I don't think it is worth the separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I converted testing’s code to Swift 2.0.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
   preferredContentSize.height = tableView.contentSize.height
}
```